# Get top 3 number of tags per month from timestamp data type in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, timestamp

I have the following dataset from BigQuery: Stackoverflow, table post_questions.

[Schema of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFXyF.png)

I would like to get the top 3 tags per month and year. The dataset goes from August 2008 until May 2020 and shows timestamps per day with time.

My original approach was to count the titles and group them per tag year, and month, so that I know which tags have the most questions asked. This, however, will give me a long query result with all the tags per month and the count (even when the tag only has one question).

I saw online that there was something called:
`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ...... ORDER BY .... DESC) AS rank.` I tried to apply it, however, I have never used it before. I am fairly new to the world of SQL.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
  tags,
  COUNT(title) AS number_of_times_used,
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM creation_date) AS month,
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM creation_date) AS year,
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions`
GROUP BY year, month, tags
```

Any suggestions on how I can get the desired result? (something like this):

```
Year: 2008   Month: 1   Tags: Android   number_of_times_used: 500
Year: 2008   Month: 1   Tags: Apple     number_of_times_used: 460
Year: 2008   Month: 1   Tags: SQL       number_of_times_used: 400
Year: 2008   Month: 2   Tags: Apple     number_of_times_used: 760
Year: 2008   Month: 2   Tags: SQL       number_of_times_used: 300
Year: 2008   Month: 2   Tags: Python    number_of_times_used: 230
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT top_tags.*
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY number_of_times_used DESC LIMIT 3) top_tags
  FROM (
    SELECT
      EXTRACT(YEAR FROM creation_date) AS year,
      EXTRACT(MONTH FROM creation_date) AS month,
      tags,
      COUNT(title) AS number_of_times_used
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions`
    GROUP BY year, month, tags
  ) t
  GROUP BY year, month
) t, t.top_tags
-- ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC, number_of_times_used DESC
```

with result

[image]